# Changing x-axis intervals

Tags: dataframe, date, indentation, x-axis

I am very new to R-studio. I cannot support my question with code because I cannot figure out how to copy and paste code from R-studio Editor into a question, likewise results from Console.

I have successfully coded a polynomial regression on my data achieved a plot with confidence intervals. But I want help changing the interval on the x-axis of my plot from days (from start) to month/year.

When I tried to post a question that included code I was unable to correct the error on this site relating to indenting code 4 spaces I have lost all that I wrote except the title! Very frustrating.

I have tried copying code from R-studio editor and pasting into my question and then highlighting then pressing ctrl k or ctrl shift k.

In the first case all the code disappears in the second case nothing changes.

Please help me with instructions for dummies for indenting code.

Thank you

My data file starts off like this:
Date     Days     cover
03/02/09  33       83

01/03/09  59       67

etc.

I think I am also likely(to encounter a problem trying to copy the whole data file <name.csv> into my question. It has 45 rows in total.     Although it looks like it might be in the link below?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbn3A.png